# How to disable IntelliJ IDEA annoying inspections (JAVA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

version: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2

There is an error that occurred in Intellij but Eclipse not.

According to the below code, the variable is StringBuilder and it's okay to append an integer or an int by the book.

But why Intellij shows me this error?  How to disable the inspections and make the red line disappeaded.

By the way, that code looks fine in eclipse.

[image]

my sameaple code

```
public class test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        Double rate = new Double(123);
        msg.append(rate == 0 ? (rate == 0 ? 0 : "-" + rate) : String.valueOf(Math.round(rate*100)).replace("0", "") + "折");
System.out.printf("yyuu:"+msg.toString());
    }
```

[image] screenshot

}

Comment: Does the exact same code work in Eclipse?

Comment: This "annoying inspection" actually prevents you from appending some form of `ToString` of an object to your `result`. You are appending an integer to a string, which might not seem so weird, because a `Integer`'s `toString()` is simply the number in string format, but what if you had tried to append a random object to the string? It would give unexpected results.

Comment: That's not an inspection, that's an error. You can't disable it. Paste your code as **text** and we can see if it's Eclipse's compiler that's buggy (as often is the case), or whether it's IDEA that's in the wrong here.

Comment: Please post the actual code and not just a screenshot of the code!

Comment: I have posted my sample code.  There is a red line but get a the correct result after run main() in Intellj.

Comment: Don't be just ignoring "annoying inspections" those are trying to help you write better code and not create bugs in your code by advising you. Intellij is a lot smarter then Eclipse which is what makes it a help of a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the IntelliJ IDEA bug, javac and eclipse compilers compile the code without errors, though Editor shows the error.

Please follow the issue created for the bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244854